# Can you arrange which troops will be used for a specific battle?

Tags: great-battles-medieval

I am stuck on a specific battle in *HISTORY Great Battles Medieval* on the English Campaign. It is for the **Perigod Province** and the specific mission is **Night Attack**, but it also has Assassinate Napoleon and Surrounded stacked up below that, which apparently I can't play until I beat this one.

This particular mission is one where your troops are scattered between a bunch of tents with enemy troops immediately surrounding you. It also doesn't give you *all* the troops you have recruited. The problem I'm having is it keeps giving me a bunch of archers up near the top where they have some very strong swordsman, and all the archers inevitably fall there. All the archers all over the place also block in all my fighting troops which can only fight in hand-to-hand combat, as the tents all over the place prevent me from getting them out.

That being said, is it possible for me to reorganize my troops so I can have something useful at the start rather than a bunch of archers, or can I cycle through to other battles for this location rather than playing Night Attack? This seems like a lost cause at the moment and I really need some extra gold to train up some more troops for the next story mission.